# mySQL grouping data together into header columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, mysql-workbench, group-concat

Here is the data I have in my database. I am trying to make each proptype a header and then comma delimited the propdetails that match.

| propid | proptype | propdetails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1234 | house | 2bedroom |
| id1234 | house | 2bathroom |
| id1234 | acreage | noland |
| id1234 | pool | nopool |
| id999 | apartment | 2bathroom |
| id999 | apartment | 2bedroom |

Here is what I am looking for in the end result.

| propid | house | acreage | pool | apartment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1234 | 2bedroom,2bathroom | noland | nopool |  |
| id999 |  |  |  | 2bathroom,2bedroom |

Here is my current query:

```
select propid a ,
case when proptype = 'house' then (SELECT group_concat(propdetails) FROM propdatabase where a=propid and proptype ='house' ) end as house,
case when proptype = 'apartment' then (SELECT group_concat(propdetails) FROM propdatabase where a=propid and proptype ='apartment') end as apartment  ,
case when proptype = 'pool' then (SELECT group_concat(propdetails) FROM propdatabase where a=propid and proptype ='pool' ) end as pool,  
case when proptype = 'acreage' then (SELECT group_concat(propdetails) FROM propdatabase where a=propid and proptype ='acreage' ) end as acreage 
from propdatabase group by proptype
```

This is my result. As you can see, the propid is being listed once per each proptype. The comma-delimiting is working which is great. I just need to figure out how to put all the information per propid onto one line.

| propid | house | acreage | pool | apartment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1234 | 2bedroom,2bathroom |  |  |  |
| id1234 |  | noland |  |  |
| id1234 |  |  | nopool |  |
| id999 |  |  |  | 2bathroom,2bedroom |

Comment: You can use `MAX()` to flatten your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of pivot-table query.

I have not tested the following, but it shows the technique. Group by the `propid` column if you want to reduce the result to one row per distinct value in that column.

Use a conditional expression like `CASE` to return the propdetails value only if another condition is met, or else NULL. The `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores NULLs.

```
SELECT propid AS a,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE proptype WHEN 'house' THEN propdetails END) AS `house`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE proptype WHEN 'acreage' THEN propdetails END) AS `acreage`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE proptype WHEN 'pool' THEN propdetails END) AS `pool`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE proptype WHEN 'apartment' THEN propdetails END) AS `apartment`
FROM propdatabase
GROUP BY propid;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much...I felt my code was close but this got me over the hump. Appreciate it!!